# Obtain location without GPS using a Telit GE864-GPS

Tags: python, geolocation, embedded

How can I obtain the location of a [Telit GE864-GPS](http://www.telit.com/en/products.php?p_id=3&p_ac=show&p=109) module using the cell network (instead of GPS) via a Python script? From my research online I have found that it looks like that you can send a HTTPS request to google (http://www.google.com/loc/m/api) to obtain this data, but I have no idea on how to do that with this device.

Comment: does the device have a data connection?

Comment: Yes this has a data connection over the cell network that is working

Comment: also I would think the unit is getting an a-gps value from the network.  Not sure if you have access to this value though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't....plain and simple.

What you can do is arrange for the cell phone network provider to allow you to see the "triangulated location" of a mobile number you own. (I remember some used to offer this.) When you install an application like "Google Latitude", the actual application is using your phone's GPS and location routines to update it's location on Google Maps.

I also think the tower may transmit location details to a GSM phone, but I have no idea how to get to the data.  This E11 call story should provide AT routines to get to the location, but I'm guessing here.

Comment: While I agree that you probably cant use Google Latitude for this, it should be relatively easy if the network(s) provide an api for this. Not sure that they do.